# SCP username with colon

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

In order to log into a dedicated server via SSH, i use the following command:

```
ssh -p 49276 myusername:1001@server.address.net.com
```

The `:1001` after the username is required for me to log in.

I'm now trying to scp some files from this server, using the following command:

`scp -P 49276 myusername:1001@server.address.net.com:/var/www /localfolder`

But when I do that, I get an error:

`Could not resolve hostname myusername: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

I assume it's because of that colon after my username. How would I SCP using these credentials?

Comment: `myusername:1001` is not a valid user name.

Comment: @hek2mgl I've never seen anything like it before, but the command above works.

Comment: @hek2mgl sure it is

Comment: @123 Where is that specified?

Comment: @hek2mgl You can authenticate users with whatever you want, I know that ldap  allows `:` in usernames.

Comment: @123 I was looking for some sort of standard. LDAP might work, I never tried that. At least a host based login can't work because records in `/etc/passwd` are separated by `:`

Comment: @hek2mgl not might, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is simply a feature of the Cisso ssh server implementation; it
>   parses the user name, and if it contains a :[0-9]+ component then it
>   understands it has to connect the session to the console port with the
>   corresponding number.

From here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187658/integer-after-username-in-openssh-client-separated-by-colon

Try this:

```
scp -P 49276 -o User=myusername:1001 server.address.net.com:/var/www /localfolder
```

Comment: Ok that works (doesn't throw that error), but after I enter my password, I get "Connection to server.address.net.com closed by remote host.". I think it's because when I log in via SSH using the SSH command i mentioned above, I then have to log in as a user to debian. Can I include an extra set of login parameters in this query?

Comment: scp seems to ignore the `-o User=` option for me (it shows trying to connect to the remote with my current-user name)

Answer (score 3):

This might be a convoluted method, but I believe it will work for your case.

You can define hosts in your `~/.ssh/config` file. There you can specify a username to use for a specific hostname. For example -

```
Host myhostname
  User myusername:1001
  HostName myhostname.com
  Port 49276
```

With this in your `~/.ssh/config` file, you'll be able to use an `scp` command similar to this -

```
scp myhostname:/var/www /localfolder
```

The host will be used together with the specified user and ports in the config file.

---

A pretty old link, but still useful info on ssh config files:
http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Comment: this is definitely working, when `-o User` is failing (my username has both `:` AND `/`)... my only problem is the username is programmatically generated and I'm not sure how dynamic it is, how often it will change. Oh well, this is better than nothing!!!